# How to replace an instance of a class with a cast, while all references to it remain working

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, casting

Let's say I have many instances of 'Item'.
Later, I want to change some of them to 'SpecialItem' which extends 'Item'.

Can I replace the instance of Item by an Instance of SpecialItem, without having to update all existing references to the old instance of Item?

...So i'd like to do 
    this = this as SpecialItem
But ofcourse, you can't do that with 'this' ;)

Comment: The instance of your class should always be as specialized as you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only cast backwards, or 'up' the inheritance chain. Something like:

```
var item:Item = mySpecialItem as Item;
```

If you need more advanced runtime swapping abilities, think about using composition instead of inheritance, eg, referencing your items as Interfaces instances instead of Class instances.

However, as @IronBCC says, if you are just looking to swap properties, you can do so by making the property public.

Answer (score 1):

No, your can't do this.
But you may use such construction:

```
class Link {
   private var _link:*;
   public get link(){}
   public set link...
}
```

and user link.link, to get your Item, and link.link = new SpecialItem(), to set new value.

Comment: ah, that's a very simple yet very helpful suggestion! tnx!